# JPQL Select Parent entity where there is no Child entity OR Child entity has a property with specific value

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa, jpql

I have a bidirectional `@OneToMany` or parent/child relationship between two entities:

```java
@Entity
public class Test {
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "test")
    private Set<Answer> answers = new HashSet<>();
}

@Entity
public class Answer {
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "test_id")
    private Test test;

    @Column
    private Boolean isCorrect;  
}
```

I want to select all `Test`s that has no `Answer` **OR** `Test`s with `Answer`'s `isCorrect` property set to `false`.
I am using `Spring Boot`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the Id of test is of type Integer:

```
public interface TestRepository extends JpaRepository<Test, Integer> {

    @Query("select t from Test t join t.answers a where a is empty or a.isCorrect = true")
    List<Test> findTestsWithNoOrIncorrectAnswers();
}
```